# Sharepoint 2013 REST API with user without admin rights

Tags: rest, file

I'm developing a web application which integrate with the SharePoint (multi-tenant). The app is supposed to upload and download files to the SharePoint.

I'm using the SharePoint 2013 REST and trying to get access tokens - authenticate using methods described in this solution:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687470(v=office.15).aspx

I've registered the app using the Seller portal. And now I redirect users to the auth URL:

```
https://<server>/_layouts/15/OAuthAuthorize.aspx?client_id=<id>&response_type=code&scope=Web.Create
```

This works fine as long as I'm logged in as the site administrator. I'm then asked to approve/trust the app (with a given permission - Web.Create).

But this doesn't work at all with non-site-admin account, when I'm logged in as non-admin user, I get just 'access denied' as a response from the OAuth.

Is there any way to use the SharePoint API - and being able to copy/read files - to the global SharePoint site using non-admin users?

Answer (score 1):

Trusting the SharePoint app must be done by an Office 365 global administrator. Users with permissions to write and read to document libraries in other site collections can copy and read files from these document libraries.